# Cannot insert question mark in postgres insert

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to run a simple Postgres SQL insert:

```
insert into "Resources" values(1, 'How are you?');
```

But the result after insert is:

```
ID        Data
---       ------
1         How are you$1
```

I know, to insert characters like single quote, I have to escape it with another single quote like: I can''t do it.

But what to do with ?

Comment: What language and libraries/frameworks are you using to execute that INSERT?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete description, using NodeJS with Knex

Comment: Found out that knex is converting ? to $1, still reading more on this :(

Comment: Don't know Knex but PostgreSQL uses numbered placeholders natively (`$1`, `$2`, ...) so it seems that Knex is sloppily replacing all question marks with PostgreSQL-style placeholders. Perhaps you should use bound parameters instead of string literals in your SQL.

Comment: Looks like a bug in knex.

Comment: @Ashutosh you need to publish the knex code you are using to generate the SQL. Otherwise, your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Knex interprets `?` and `??` as positional bindings. You would normally use them inside a `knex.raw()` statement to safely inject some kind variable. For example:

```
knex.raw('UPDATE my_table SET my_column = ?', [someVariable])
```

Binding parameters like this is often necessary with raw statements to ensure whatever you're injecting is safely escaped.

So that's **why** you are seeing that behavior. The good news is, you can just escape question marks. From the [Knex.js documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw-parameter-binding):

> To prevent replacement of ? one can use the escape sequence \\?.

Comment: So knex requires additional escaping on the off-chance your text contains `?`. That doesn't sound right or good at all.

Comment: @vitaly-t It doesn't need additional escaping. You should not pass value as constant strings to driver like knex.raw(`select * from table where name = 'who are you?'`), but as this answer states you should do knex.raw(`select * from table where name = ?`, ['who are you?']) to pass values as value bindings to db driver. This is simply because knex cannot implement SQL parser to be able to know which parts are values and which not.

Comment: @Mi  I disagree that you should not be able to pass ? within a constant string.  This is a raw query meaning we have formed it elsewhere.  For example, we build the query to be passed as a stored procedure call.