# Postgres: filtering using like operator on jsonb array readonly column

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a SQL query. It's a very complex query. In this question, I will only extract out the part that I am struggling to make it easier to explain.

I have a jsonb readonly array column in the select statement of my query as follows.

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, json_agg(column_3)::jsonb as item_ids from items
```

See in particular this part: `json_agg(column_3)::jsonb`.

The query return an array of text/ string for `item_ids` column. If I want to filter if any of the given parameter or string is equal to any of the element/ value/ string in the `item_ids` array, I can do something like this.

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, json_agg(column_3)::jsonb as item_ids from items 
WHERE item_ids ? 'item_1'
```

That will return the row where any of the element of item_ids array is exactly equal to 'item_1'.

But I want something like like operator and I want it to be case insensitive.

Metaphorically, something like this.

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, json_agg(column_3)::jsonb as item_ids from items 
    WHERE ANY(item_ids) ILIKE '%item_1%'
```

How can I do that?

The query returns the data in the following format.

```
column_1   | column_2    | item_ids
------------------------------------------------------
row1 col 1 | row1 col 2  | [ item_1, item_2, item_3 ]
row2 col 1 | row2 col 2  | [ item_1, item_2, item_3 ]
```

Comment: Can you update your post with some sample data?

Comment: Neither your first query, nor your second query will work, because you miss non-aggregated fields in your GROUP BY clause. A good idea would be to apply filtering before the aggregation, but your abstract, partially already manipulated data won't help to develop that idea.

Comment: Actually, I am only looking for the jsonb operator to do that kind of filtering. The query is just a abstraction as I mentioned.

Comment: The query is already working. It is just filtering part that is missing.

Comment: What is the data type of `column3`?

Comment: What postgres version are you running? You could use a jsonpath expression

Comment: @Bergi it is a readonly column. It is not part of the table. But it has jsonb datatype.

Comment: Array of string. AS I mentioned something like [item_1, item_2, item_3]

Comment: What does "readonly" mean, are you saying it is generated from a subquery/view? Also you're still unclear whether `column3` has type `jsonb`, `text`, or even `text[]`. (Mind you: asking about `column3`, which is passed into `jsonb_agg`, not about `item_ids` which is `jsonb`)

Comment: Sorry, column_3 itself has string/ varchar datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ANY` only works on the right hand side, so `value ILIKE ANY patterns`. There is no reversed operator where you could use `pattern ??? ANY values` (unless you create yourself a custom operator), see [Postgresql ILIKE/LIKE ANY returns no results when using a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60013226/1048572). You will need to use a subquery in your condition, which is easier done with an actual `text[]` than a `jsonb` holding an array of strings.

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, item_ids::jsonb
FROM (
  SELECT *, array_agg(column_3) AS item_ids
  FROM items
  -- GROUP BY something, I assume
) AS agg_items
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM unnest(item_ids) AS item_id
  WHERE item_id ILIKE '%item_1%'
);
```

You might be able to rewrite this into a `HAVING` condition depending on how exactly your aggregation works.

---

Alternatively, if you're dead-set on using a `jsonb` value, you can use a [json path query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) with the `like_regex` operator:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, item_ids
FROM (
  SELECT *, jsonb_agg(column_3) AS item_ids
  FROM items
  -- GROUP BY something, I assume
) AS agg_items
WHERE item_ids @? '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "item_1" flag "i")';
```

Comment: I tried, but I don't think the syntax is right. It is complaining.  syntax error at or near "'$[*] $11 (@ like_regex "item_1"

Comment: @WaiYanHein How did you get a `$11` in place of the `?`? It sounds like your database library is buggy and did attempt parameter substitution inside a string literal.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I am running that using Knex. The placeholders. Another issue.

Comment: Yeah, [looks like a Knex bug](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3304) to me, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375925/cannot-insert-question-mark-in-postgres-insert

Comment: Anyway. This works in raw query. Thanks a lot.  I will just try using the first solution.

Comment: The first solution is actually a lot better. But I also wanted to learn how I can do that on jsonb datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Finding something inside a json array is generally less performant than attempting to use standard sql operations on a table.

A viable option is to search for the existence of one such item among your data with an `EXISTS` operator. In this way, the `WHERE` clause will filter out all group_id values that don't have pattern at least once, and the json arrays you'll be building are only the ones you need.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT group_id, 
       JSONB_AGG(column_3) AS item_ids 
FROM items i1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM items i2 WHERE i1.column_id = i2.column_id ILIKE '<your_pattern>')
GROUP BY group_id
```

On a side note, there are two problems with your queries:

- the former two are missing non-aggregated fields in the `GROUP BY` clause
- the `WHERE` clause of the third query will apply before the aggregation is carried out, and for this reason, such clause does not make sense if you're attempting to work on the computed json

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I am only looking for the operator not an alternative solution.

Comment: I'll keep this for other people that may have this same problem and look for alternative ways.